# Is there any evidence that Voldemort was a nationalist?

Tags: harry-potter, voldemort, politics

In a recent radio programme for the BBC J.K. Rowling discussed Voldemort's personal ideology and philosophy.

> **Bridget Christie:** When there were studies that found that people who read the books had more empathy and were more tolerant was that something that was quite a...?
>
> **J.K. Rowling:** Well, it's an amazing thing to read. And those themes are deeply embedded in the books. Ideas of being different. Racism is obviously there in allegorical form. Totalitarianism is there because Voldemort is obviously an authoritarian...I wouldn't say he's a populist but I suppose he's a kind of nationalist. So, yeah, those ideas are all in there and it's an incredible thing to think that people would have softened in their attitudes because of reading them.
> <sub>*([The Museum of Curiosity](https://www.bbc.co.uk/sounds/play/m000ckw7), Christmas Special, BBC Radio 4, 23rd December 2019)*.</sub>

Plainly there's plenty of evidence that Voldemort was a totalitarian and an authoritarian. The claim that he was a nationalist strikes me as being less clear. Yes, Voldemort restricted his campaign of terror to Britain and didn't show much interest in the rest of the world. But he was much more self-evidently pro-wizards than he was pro-UK.

I can't really think of any examples from the books where Voldemort exhibits nationalist tendencies. Are there any such examples? (I'm primarily interested in the books and Pottermore rather than other forms of canon).

Comment: It's pretty clear that JKR randomly accuses people of being like characters from her books in order to make a point. This time she seems to have gone the other way.

Comment: Are you sure by "kind of nationalist" she didn't mean something like "the wizarding nation"?

Comment: Found out something new about yourself, did you?

Answer (score 58, accepted):

**Voldemort's nationalism does not necessitate a connection to the UK.**

The term *[nation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nation)* is often used as a shorthand for *nation state.*  However, in itself it does not necessarily imply a shared territory, only a shared origin, bloodline, common culture, etc.  In many cases it is used to describe a diaspora of people such as Native American tribes or Jews (The Nation of Israel is an old term for the Jewish diaspora all over the world).

In Voldemort's case, his nationalism is what is referred to as *ethnic nationalism.*  His pursuit is very much that of common culture, bloodline, and possibly origin.  He may want to create a world-wide nation state, or he may want to stick with the UK - but, in either case, he has a very clear idea of who the constituents of his nation are and aren't.

Comment: So, the *wizarding nation* then.

Comment: @Valorum Sure.  Or *Voldemort's wizards*, but then they might have to fight Volkswagen over the logo.

Comment: @Valorum And preferably only the pure-blooded part of that, I'd presume.

Comment: @Mast - Purebloodedness is something of a myth. The Death Eaters seem content to allow half-bloods among their ranks as long as they aren't Muggle-lovers.

Comment: When it's really all about power, anything and everything is forgiven if you help.

Comment: And, of course, He Who Must Not Be Named was a half-blood himself.  Though I guess he could make himself an exception if he wanted to narrow his nation to the pure-bloodeded.

Comment: @JohnBollinger Kind of like Adolf Hitler, short and dark haired, who promoted Aryan race of high and blonde people? I guess Voldemort would prefer to only work with pure-bloods, but in absence of those Muggle-haters are good enough.

Comment: @Yksisarvinen Voldemort considered anyone who wasn't pure-blooded to be next to worthless. Hitler on the other hand did consider Aryan traits to be ideal, but didn't considered those with black hair or brown eyes to be "subhuman" like he did some other races.

Comment: @forest Except, one of his close confidants was Severus Snape, Halfblood.  Voldemort seems to consider *muggles* subhuman, but muggle**borns** to "merely" be the dregs of society.  The trials in DH read more like Umbridge deciding to go "above and beyond"...

Comment: @Chronocidal Ah that makes sense. It's been a while since I read the books!